# Why doesnt my script work? not finding desired output

Tags: powershell

i am trying to define a set of branches (sub divisions with each division) so that teams can work

I want it to check to see if there's a branch (division), if there's a branch replace it the ITOSB valid division in the extensionattribute1 field

```
$allusers =  get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "OU=IOSB,OU=OIS,OU=SACHQ,OU=carb,DC=ad,DC=arb,DC=ca,DC=gov"
-Properties * | Select-Object SAMaccountName, ExtensionAttribute1, Department Write-Output $allusers

$validDivision=@('ITOSB') $validDivisionUsers=@() $invalidDivisionUsers=@() $log=@()

$log += "Run: $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm") $PSCommandPath"

#search through all users in ITOSB ForEach ( $user in $allusers ) {
    #Get User's Division from users distinguishedName
    $PossibleUserDivision = @($user.DistinguishedName -split(',cn=|,ou=|,dc=|'))
    #plit = take out cn,ou,and dc so you can loop through distinguished name

}
    ForEach ( $Division in $PossibleUserDivision){

        if ( $validDivision -contains $user.ExtensionAttribute1){
            $userDivision="$Division"
            Write-Output "Valid division found $($user.validDivision)"
            break #Stop when we find a match

        } else {
            $userDivision='$null' #No division found
    }       Write-Output "Valid division not found"

    if ( !$userDivision ){
        $log += "Error: No valid department found: $($user.samAccountName) $($user.DistinguishedName) $($user.extensionAttribute1)"
        break
    }
    if ( $userDivision -eq $user.ExtensionAttribute1 ){
        $validDivisionUsers+=$user
    } else {

        $invalidDivisionUsers+=$user
        try {
            $log += "Changing `"$($user.extensionAttribute1)`" to `"$($UserDivision)`" for user `"$($user.SamAccountName)`""
           # Set-ADUser -Identity $user -extensionattribute1 "$userDivision"
            write-ouput "User $user added to ITOSB"
        } 
        catch {
            $log += "Error: Unable to set Department for $user, do you have permissions? exiting..."
            exit 1
        }
    } }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the output you're currently getting, as well as the output you expect/desire? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: see picture above, i want the script to only fill extensionattribute1 if its missing

Comment: no errors, i dont even get to my setaduser command (it doesnt produce anything

Comment: sorry, i do get valid division found as well

Comment: Ok, I don't want to sound rude but your code doesn't make any sense. Half of the actual code is commented and is almost impossible to understand what you're actually looking to accomplish with your script. Can you please edit the code and clean it up so we can make sense of it?